# DeferredResult don't return value on AJAX request

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I´m using DeferredResult to make an async request, and I´m using AJAX on client side. But every time that I want to return one of this async request from another thread, the response that I receive in my client is not the one that I pass in the `setResult`.

```
 deferredResult.setResult("foo");
```

I only receive `Status 200 OK`.
Looking in Firebug I don't see any response tab. Just an XML tab that says:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipa
```

I´m using Spring with Jackson for the HttpCopnversionMapping on renders.
Looks like the HTTPRequest is expecting a Json format but the return is empty or not in the format that expect.

Am I doing something wrong?
Regards.